# What is the code to get into the Memorize Headquarters?

Tags: remember-me

Episode five of Remember Me has you steal the memories from Captain Trace, one of the security personnel from Memorize Corporation. Playing his remembrance reveals a keypad which requires a four digit code to open the door and get into the Memorize Headquarters building:

[image: Memorize Headquarters entry code]

Playing his second remembrance reveals a riddle:

- My first is second when counting them all
- My second is frozen when absolute
- My third has all its senses
- My fourth tap dances like a spider
- ...and all put together I can go through a door

What is the code to get into the Memorize Headquarters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first [digit] is second when counting them all

> Starting from one, the second number you count is 2

My second [digit] is frozen when absolute

> A reference to [absolute zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero)

My third [digit] has all its senses

> Humans have five senses

My fourth [digit] tap dances like a spider

> Spiders have 8 legs

---

...and all put together I can go through a door

> The final solution is 2058

Answer (score -1):

****2058
is the answer** 
enjoy guys have fun yaya great game**